# Ubercart entries in menu_links table causing performance issues

Tags: ubercart, performance

Drupal 6:
I have found around 130 entries in the menu_links table such as:

- user/123/order
- user/5a9689f90da4d0d012de104d7da67a8b/order/
- user/123/order//invoice

These entries cause a user_load to happen which seems to be irrespective of which user is logged in.

Deleting these entries results in around 1000 less queries being run on a page load.

My question is, is it safe to delete these entries and how would they have ended up in the menu_links table in the first place?

Comment: Sounds similar to this bug I filed against Druapl 7/8 http://drupal.org/node/1710656

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give this patch a try? I can't answer you're question directly but I think this might help with all the user loads http://drupal.org/node/1710656#comment-6474030

Comment: Yes that patch does exactly what I need. Around 1200 queries down to 200 queries. However it does seem that there are still entries in the menu_links table that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it fulfills my primary issue of performance, however why those entries were created is still a mystery. There is a chance they were created by one of the Money Scripts modules or a custom hook.